# C++ Algorithmically Simple Recursive Palindrome Checker

Tags: c++, recursion

I wrote a string palindrome checker which my instructor says is more complex than it needs to be. I've read similar threads and googled around, but I'm completely stumped as to how to get it to work with fewer steps than this...

```
void isPal(string str){
int length = str.length();
if(length <= 1) cout << "Palindrome" << endl;//check for zero or one digit numbers
else if(str.at(0) == str.at(length -1)) {
    str = str.substr(1, (length - 2));
    isPal(str);}
else cout << "Not a palindrome." << endl;{
    cin >> str;}
```

Comment: You should just split string in halfs and compare them?

Comment: Use two indexes together, you don't want to use .substr.

Comment: @elmigranto The task for this problem is to use recursion. Otherwise I could just compare the whole string to its reverse, correct?

Comment: @herohuyongtao how do I knock off the first and last characters without using .substr?

Comment: You just need to *move* the indexes.

Comment: @brock Yes, correct. `std::equal(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), s.crbegin());`.

Comment: @brock See my answer for how to use two indexes, use recursion or without.

Comment: @brock that's beautifully short, but it's a shame this ends up testing the whole string, instead of stopping when it reaches the mid point

Comment: @brock http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal gives `std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size()/2, s.rbegin());`

Comment: @brock Since this has been brought up again by a comment to my answer: see the extension to my answer ("Later").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this:

```
int is_pal(int start, int end, string &str)
{
    if (start >= end)
        return 1;
    if (str[start] != str[end])
        return 0;
    return is_pal(++start, --end, str);   
}
```

Call the method from main. Let me know if that helps.. :)

Comment: had to replace `char *str` with `string str` but this worked. Thanks.

Comment: This is not "algorithmically simple" as it requires the caller to add two index values in the call.

Comment: @elmigranto If you don't understand it, don't edit it.

Comment: Better to pass the string by const reference :P

Comment: @Drongo funny that this question now has over 10,000 views, yet neither it or the accepted answer (yours) has a single upvote...

Comment: @brock > Ha ha ha thats true. May be because the people who views this question, might not have any account in SO. It is kind of a basic question which is popular among new students. And most of them don't have an account in SO. But yeah if it helped at least 1/3 of those viewers, I think it's just awesome!!!

Answer (score 6):

### Use recursion

If you still want to use recursion, do something like:

```
bool isPal(const string &str, int start, int end)
{
    if (start >= end)   
        return true;
    if (str[start] != str[end])
        return false;
    return isPal(str, ++start, --end);   
}
```

And call `isPal(str, 0, str.length()-1)` in the main body. The idea is to use two indexes and move them as you don't want to use `substr()` every time in recursion.

### Without recursion

Actually this problem is easy to do without using recursion as follows:

```
bool isPal(const string &str)
{
    int start=0, end=str.length()-1;
    while (start < end) {
        if (str[start++] != str[end--]) 
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'll upvote if you fix this to use a const reference for the string parameters

Answer (score 2):

It should be a function returning true or false, and not print a message. The parameter should be a single string object.

```
bool isPalindrome( const std::string & word ){
  std::string::const_iterator fwd = word.begin();
  std::string::const_iterator rev = word.end();
  if( rev - fwd <= 1 ) return true;
  if( *fwd++ != *--rev ) return false;
  return isPalindrome( std::string( fwd, rev ) );
}
```

**Later**

So a *recursive* solution with a *single parameter* requires a new string object with each recursion. This has been critizised as being "horrible" - but is it really? An algorithm must be judged in relation to the domain for which it is intended.

Let's assume that this domain is the words of the English language. There is more than 1.000,000 words in the English language but the number of palindromes is less than 200. So the probability that the recursion has to go all the way to N/2 iterations is almost negligible. Also, the percentage of words with equal first and last letters is very small, and therefore not even a single recursion is required in most cases.

Another possible domain is random strings composed from the letters 'a' to 'z': more than 96% will not require even a single recursive call. "Horrible"? Hardly.

If one does want to avoid this "horror", one has three options: avoid recursion, use a second method (to be called from the first) or require more than one argument.

The third variant has been proposed by others, requiring no less than three arguments, asking the user to provide redundant information with a rather messy call, e.g.:

```
string word = "evitative";
bool res = isPal( word, 0, word.length()-1 );
```

Not really pleasing, is it? - But one can do better than that!

```
bool isPal2( string::const_iterator fwd, string::const_iterator rev ){
    return rev - fwd <= 1 || *fwd++ == *--rev && isPal2( fwd, rev );
}
```

With a moderately complex call:

```
string word = "reviver";
bool res = isPal2( word.begin(), word.end() );
```

Now we have avoided the creation of string objects even in those rare cases of palindromes or "palindromoids" at the cost of one additional parameter, at least without redundant information.

Comment: Forgive me, I don't understand the parameter `string & word`.

Comment: @brock This is the notation for parameter passing by reference. In C, you had to use "type* par" in the parameter spec, "&variable" in the call and "*par" in the body of the function to achieve (more or less) the same effect.

Comment: horrible `O(n^2)` algorithm, since it creates a new string for each pass

Comment: @Alnitak I'm sure you can show us a *recursive* version that's algorithmically simple, i.e., *a single function*, and with the *signature as shown in the question*.

Comment: well (apart from the return vs message issue) yours is pretty functionally equivalent to the one the OP posted that he said wasn't good enough - both create a new string

Comment: @Alnitak So what about Rashad's answer? You have to call with 2 additional parameters - and what's the O() value there? - And where is your superior solution avoiding all disadvantages? - Also, consider: what is the probability of this recursion going all the way to n? For random strings and for words in the dictionary?

Comment: Rashad's answer is trivially fixed by making the passed parameter a const reference. The additional parameters make no difference to the complexity. I've nothing to add to herohuyongtao's answer.

Comment: @Alnitak wrote, "I've nothing to add to herohuyongtao's answer" Hmm... Maybe look at my edited answer?

Comment: Point taken about the statistical likelihood of being passed a palindrome, but I'd still take the position of going for O(n) worst-case with O(1) best-case rather than O(n^2).  Re: function parameters, since this is C++ one can always write a function with the same name but a different signature to handle the bare `is_Pal(const std::string& s)` version and then either does the length or iterator thing.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm make it not recursive is a try

```
int i = 0;
int j = str.length() - 1;
bool isPalindrome = true;

while(i < j && isPalindrome)
{
   if(str[i++] != str[j--]) isPalindrome = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm supposed to use recursion on this problem.

Comment: Haha, np.  Looks like the other answer is the recursive equivalent anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check whether a string is palindrome or not, you can do it easily as:

1. insert the string into a **vector** suppose v
2. reverse the **vector** v and insert it to another vector called suppose v1.
3. if v == v1, then palindrome, otherwise not.

**i've just suggested a method to check palindrome. nothing else.**

Comment: Need... More... Vectors... :) Just use `std::equal` and reverse iterators.

Answer (score -2):

```
bool isPalindrome(char str[], int i) {

    int x=(strlen(str)-i);
       if (i==0) {
      return true;
   }
   if (str[x]!=str[i-1]) {
      return false;
   }
   return isPalindrome(str, i-1);
}
```

Comment: by invoking `strlen()` inside the loop you made the algorithm O(n^2) instead of O(n)

Comment: Answers which just provide code, with no explanation are not particularly useful

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! While this code block might answer the question; you should try to improve your answer with relevant explanation with the code. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer